# What is causing incorrect number of positional arguments on my callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have to send the failure message of tasks through teams.

```
webhook = Teams(
    url
)

default_args = {
    ...
    "provide_context": True,
    "on_failure_callback": webhook.failure
}
```

My class is with the methods is:

```
class Teams(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(Teams, self).__init__()
        self.url = url

    def _initialise_webhook(self):
        self.message_ = pymsteams.connectorcard(
            self.url
        )

    def failure(self, **context):
        self._initialise_webhook()
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        print(context)
        print(context['task_instance'])
```

I am getting an error as following upon execution:

```
task.on_failure_callback(context)
TypeError: failure() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `def failure(self, context):`?

Comment: In that case it says:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
@GrzegorzSkibinski

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to call the failure function like this `obj.failure(context)`
python is treating this as positional arguments.
For passing keyword arguments you have to pass like this `obj.failure(**context)`

for more about keyword arguments  you can read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/#:%7E:text=A%20keyword%20argument%20is%20where,which%20they%20were%20printed%20out.)